# Understand Float "method" from book "Programming Ruby"

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the book *Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0*. And on page 44 there is this example:

```
class BookInStock
  def inintialize(isbn, price)
    @isbn = isbn
    @price = Float(price)
  end
end
```

The book explain that `Float` is a method that turns something to a float number. But isn't method name starts with lowercase? Then I invested the method of `self` using `puts self.methods`, and I didn't see any method named Float and `self.methods.grep /F/` gives an empty array. So where is this method comes from. Or if it is a class, how can class be used this way?

Comment: Method names *may* start with a lowercase. And in general, they should. `Float` is a [convenience method on `Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float).

Comment: Yes, I checked the Kernel module and see that there is a Float method there. I just wonder why it isn't in the list of "methods".

Comment: Because it has nothing to do with the class you're currently in (`BookInStock`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from creating a method name starting with a capital letter. What Ruby does when it encounters this is first check if it can find it in the table of constants (i.e. a class), if not, it will check if it is defined as a method.

In this particular instance, [`Float()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) is defined in the [`Kernel`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html) module, as a sort of factory. The same convenience methods exist for all the primitive types you will find in Ruby, e.g. [`Integer()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), [`Array()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Array), [`Hash()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash), etc.

Comment: Thank you! When I use "Go to definition" in RubyMine, it leads me to a class definition, I guess it's kind of misleading.

Comment: @Chris.Zou: Yes. I would assume RubyMine looks it up the same way Ruby does. Because it finds the class first, it takes you there.

Comment: No. Constants can't take arguments, only methods can. Ruby will never look for a constant if you pass an argument. It knows it's a method because it has arguments.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Oh. It seems I got it wrong then. Can you please point me to the source?

Comment: There are several questions here on SO about that, I believe. `Foo` is always a constant, `Foo()`, `Foo bar` and `bar.Foo` are always methods, simply because constants can't have receivers or arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the footnote in Chapter 8.1 from the same book:

> You won’t get an immediate error if you start a method name with an uppercase letter, but when Ruby sees you calling the method, it might guess that it is a constant, not a method invocation, and as a result it may parse the call incorrectly. **By convention, methods names starting with an uppercase letter are
>   used for type conversion. The `Integer` method, for example, converts its parameter to an integer.**

Examples are `Array`, `Hash`, `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Rational`, `Complex`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A method can have the same name as a class. So `Float` could be defined as a method of Kernel like this

```
def Float(x)
    x.to_f
end
```

And as a class like this

```
class Float
end
```

Of course, this isn't how they are defined in Ruby, but you could do this with another class or method. There is an article [here](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2015/3/24/playing-with-constants-methods-and-superclasses.html) on this, about methods, classes, and constants that all share the same name. It's very interesting. You'll also notice `Float` is a method of Kernel because you can do `Kernel.Float(x)`. This can actually be done with other methods. For example `puts` can be called like `Kernel.puts(a_string)`

Comment: The reason why you can call `Kernel.Float` is not because `Float` is a method of `Kernel`. At least not directly. `Kernel` is an instance of `Module`, `Module` is a subclass of `Object`, `Object` includes `Kernel`, so the reason why you can call `Kernel.Float` is not because `Float` is a method of `Kernel`, it's because `Kernel` is an instance of `Kernel`.